# How can I add objects to a json file without ruining the format of the file?

Tags: c#, json

I have a json file that I manually filled with information, and I want to add more to it using C#
I tried couple of things, but they ruined the format of the file

Comment: _"but they ruined the format of the file"_ - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Parse, add what you need, turn into JSON again.

Comment: If you need an easy appendable file format then json might be the wrong option.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to try and add to the file, and provide an example of what the formatted file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a C# dev, but I may suggest you general advice:

- read file and parse it as JSON object with any json parsing library available for C#.
- put your data as new node to place where you want to modify.
- convert it to string and rewrite the file. (the library may convert it to string by itself)